# Zurb Foundation adjust topbar dropdown height

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have adjusted the height of topbar within _topbar.scss to 76 though this also seems to be affecting the dropdown

```
// Height and margin
$topbar-height: rem-calc(76) !default;
```

I have changed around 430 to the following, which reduces the height of the dropdown, but then pushes the top margins out on the menu

```
      // Styling elements inside of dropdowns
  .dropdown {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    #{$default-float}: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    @include topbar-hide-dropdown();

    li {
      width: 100%;
      height: $topbar-height/2;

      a {
        font-weight: $topbar-dropdown-link-weight;
        padding: 8px $topbar-link-padding;
        &.parent-link {
          font-weight: $topbar-link-weight;
        }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe clarifying what exactly you want to happen would help. That image shows the menu `li`s overlapping each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inspect the HTML-code of a dropdown you will find that the title and items of the menu render all in the same `ul` (modified by javascript), for instance:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li>
<li class="parent-link hide-for-medium-up"><a class="parent-link js-generated" href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a></li>
<li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, yes when i change `$topbar-height` the height of all these items changes.

With `$topbar-height: rem-calc(90);` my dropdown will look like that shown in the figure below:

[image]

Now i think a possible solution for your issue can be to make the items of the dropdown less high after applying `$topbar-height: rem-calc(90);`. This should effect every item after the first two items in the `ul.dropdown`.

You can use the SCSS code like that shown beneath to do that:

```
.top-bar ul.dropdown li:nth-child(n+2) a, 
.top-bar ul.dropdown li.active:nth-child(n+2) a {
line-height: rem-calc(45);
}
```

(in your situation you should put the above code at the end of `_topbar.scss`)

After recompiling your code, the dropdown now should look as follows:

[image]

Finally you should notice that editing `_topbar.scss` is bad practice in most cases, cause doing so disable you from updating foundation. You should create a `app.scss` and compile that file:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";

.top-bar ul.dropdown li:nth-child(n+2) a, 
.top-bar ul.dropdown li.active:nth-child(n+2) a {
line-height: rem-calc(45);
}
```

and your (custom) `_setttings.scss`:

```
$topbar-height: rem-calc(90);
```